# How can I get a group of shapes to change colors based on which one was selected?

Tags: vba, button, grouping, shapes

I have 4 shapes, in a group, 'Customer, Vendor, Prospect, Suspect.' I want to be able to select one shape to change the style, but only allow one of them to be that style at a time. So if the CustomerStyle is msoShapeStyle31, then I want the other 3 to be all msoShapeStyle32; but if the user clicks on one of the 3 other buttons, that button should change to msoShapeStyle31 and the remaining  3 converts to msoShapeStyle32. I hope that makes sense.

The RelationshipButtons is the group, which I plan on outputting a cell value based on which one of the shapes is msoShapeStyle31.

Here is what I have, but it isn't right because several of them are turning to msoShapeStyle31 at the same time when it should only be one at a time. Any help?

```
Sub Button_Colors()
With Sheet1

Dim CustomerButton As Shape, VendorButton As Shape, ProspectButton As Shape, SuspectButton As Shape, RelationshipButtons As Shape
Set CustomerButton = .Shapes("CustomerButton")
Set VendorButton = .Shapes("VendorButton")
Set ProspectButton = .Shapes("ProspectButton")
Set SuspectButton = .Shapes("SuspectButton")
Set RelationshipButtons = .Shapes("RelationshipButtons")

Dim CustomerStyle As Integer, VendorStyle As Integer, ProspectStyle As Integer, SuspectStyle As Integer
CustomerStyle = CustomerButton.ShapeStyle
VendorStyle = VendorButton.ShapeStyle
ProspectStyle = ProspectButton.ShapeStyle
SuspectStyle = SuspectButton.ShapeStyle

With RelationshipButtons
    If CustomerStyle = 31 Then
        CustomerStyle = msoShapeStylePreset32
        VendorStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
        ProspectStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
        SuspectStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
    ElseIf VendorStyle = 31 Then
        CustomerStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
        VendorStyle = msoShapeStylePreset32
        ProspectStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
        SuspectStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
    ElseIf ProspectStyle = 31 Then
        CustomerStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
        VendorStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
        ProspectStyle = msoShapeStylePreset32
        SuspectStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
    ElseIf SuspectStyle = 31 Then
        CustomerStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
        VendorStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
        ProspectStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
        SuspectStyle = msoShapeStylePreset32
    End If
End With
    CustomerButton.ShapeStyle = CustomerStyle
    VendorButton.ShapeStyle = VendorStyle
    ProspectButton.ShapeStyle = ProspectStyle
    SuspectButton.ShapeStyle = SuspectStyle
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What would you want to do with `RelationshipButtons` shape? That `With ... End With` does not make any sense, since nothing from 'RelationshipButtons' side is involved... What kind of controls are your buttons? ActiveX controls, or Form controlls? You should use their `Click` event, I think. I cannot understand how does that code works, even not perfectly. Didn't you say that the style must be changed only when one of the buttons is pressed? If yes, where in your code a button is pressed? If not, how do you imagine that the `Click` event is used by your code?

Comment: Are your shapes really Buttons, or ordinary rectangles? How did you create them? Sorry, but do you know what a button is in VBA?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. They are shapes, which I am using as buttons. I realize there is a difference.

Comment: The RelationshipButtons shape is the group of shapes; is it not necessary?

Comment: Necessary for WHAT? Did you, at least, assign macros to that pseudo buttons?

Comment: I did, but not for the group yet, I intend to set a cell value based on which shape is msoShapeStyle31.

Comment: Apologies if in my confusion I was unclear, I edited the question

Comment: Can you explain which is your purpose of doing what you describe in your question? If you group the four shapes you cannot press each of them, anymore...

Comment: Do you have on the specific sheet some other shapes besides the ones you enumerated?

Comment: Nevermind, it is enough that the enumerated shapes exist on the same sheet and all of them have the Tim's macro `ToggleShapes` (a little adapted) assigned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach which is a little more concise:

```
'all the shpes in the group "Group 6" are assigned this macro
Sub ToggleShapes()
    Dim shp As Shape, clr
    clr = Application.Caller  '<< this is the name of the clicked shape
    Debug.Print clr
    'loop over the grouped shapes and set the color according to their name
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 6").GroupItems
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(shp.Name = clr, vbRed, vbYellow)
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**All the credit must go to @Tim Williams!**
I just adapted his code to exactly do what (I understood) Michelle needs. It looks that Michelle only now understood the difference between a shape and a button and I have some doubts she will manage to adapt this Tim's nice piece of code in the way she started.

As Tim Williams said, you must assign this macro to all shapes involved. The macro has to exist in a module. The code does not check if the rectangles name are the ones you posted. It assumes (in this variant) that they are...

```
Sub ToggleShapes()
    Dim clr As String, arrNames As Variant, El As Variant
    arrNames = Array("CustomerButton", "VendorButton", "ProspectButton", "SuspectButton")
    clr = Application.Caller
        For Each El In arrNames
            If ActiveSheet.Shapes(El).Name = clr Then
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(El).ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset32
                'do something else if the case...
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(El).ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset31
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

I have also supposed that the single purpose of the code is not to only color the background. I thought that, besides that, it must also do something...